# parsing JSON request failed - FIXED

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

Everything works fine, the data is already saving into mySQL but the thing is I'm still having this error "parsing JSON request failed". I'm not pretty sure where the error comes from and its cause.

Script:

```
$("#add_submit_form").on("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).serialize());

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "add_submit.php",
    data: "subject_code="+subj_code,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data){
      alert("success");
    },
    error:function(x,e){
        if(x.status==0){
            alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
        }else if(x.status==404){
            alert('Requested URL not found.');
        }else if(x.status==500){
            alert('Internel Server Error.');
        }else if(e=='parsererror'){
            alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
        }else if(e=='timeout'){
            alert('Request Time out.');
        }else {
            alert('Unknow Error.\n'+x.responseText);
        }
    }


  });        
});
```

PHP:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
require_once('/include/connect.php');

/** Pass the user inputs into re-useable variables **/
$subject_code = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['subject_code']));
$subject_name = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['subject_name']));
$subject_course = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['subject_course']));
$subject_day = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['subject_day']));
$subject_time = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['subject_time']));
$subject_year = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['subject_year']));
$subject_section = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['subject_section']));
$subject_room = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['subject_room']));

/** Prepare the SQL statement **/
$stmt = $database->prepare('
    INSERT INTO schedule(
        sched_id,
        subject_code,
        subject_name,
        subject_course,
        subject_day,
        subject_time,
        subject_year,
        subject_section,
        subject_room)
    VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)');

/** Bind the statement into parameters**/
$stmt->bind_param('issssssss',
        $sched_id,
        $subject_code,
        $subject_name,
        $subject_course,
        $subject_day,
        $subject_time,
        $subject_year,
        $subject_section,
        $subject_room);

/** Execute the statement **/
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt){
    $response_array['status'] = 'success';
}
else{
    $response_array['status'] = 'error';
}

echo json_encode($return);

exit;
```

HTML:

```
<form action="add_submit.php" method="POST" id="add_submit_form">
    <section id="add_subject_response">response</section> <!--Hidden section for RESPONSE on ADD SCHEDULE-->         
    <td>
        <select id="add_subject_code" name="subject_code">;
        <?php
            $stmt = $database->prepare('SELECT * FROM subject_schedule');
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            echo "<option id='' value=''>Select Subject Code</option>";
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $subj_code = $row['subject_code'];
                    $subj_name = $row['subject_name'];
                    $subj_course = $row['subject_course'];
                    echo "<option id='" . $subj_course . "' class='" . $subj_name  . "' value='" . $subj_code . "'>" . $subj_code . "</option>";
                }
        ?>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input id="add_subject_name" class="add_required" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="subject_name"></td>
    <td><input id="add_subject_course" class="add_required" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="subject_course"></td>
    <td><input id="add_subject_day" class="add_required" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="subject_day" maxlength="10"></td>
    <td><input id="add_subject_time" class="add_required" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="subject_time" maxlength="20"></td>
    <td><input id="add_subject_year" class="add_required" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="subject_year" maxlength="10"></td>
    <td><input id="add_subject_section" class="add_required" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="subject_section" maxlength="10"></td>
    <td><input id="add_subject_room" class="add_required" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="subject_room" maxlength="10"></td>
    <td><input id="add_submit_button" type="submit" value="Add Schedule"></td>
</form>
```

console log:

```
subject_code=FIL111&subject_name=Sining+ng+Komunikasyon&subject_course=Bachelor+of+Science+in+Information+Technology&subject_day=day_test&subject_time=time_test&subject_year=year_test&subject_section=section_te&subject_room=room_test
```

changes: remove mysql_real_escape_string

Script:

```
data: $(this).serialize(),
```

PHP:

```
echo json_encode($response_array);
```

Outcome: Save on mySQL, console log still the same, error still the same

Dev Tool Result :

> array(8) { 
>     ["subject_code"]=> 
>     string(6) "ENG111" 
>     ["subject_name"]=> 
>     string(20) "Communication Arts 1" 
>     ["subject_course"]=> 
>     string(45) "Bachelor of Science in Information Technology" 
>     ["subject_day"]=> 
>     string(4) "test" 
>     ["subject_time"]=> 
>     string(4) "test" 
>     ["subject_year"]=> 
>     string(4) "test" 
>     ["subject_section"]=> 
>     string(4) "test" 
>     ["subject_room"]=> 
>     string(4) "test" 
>   } 
>   {"status":"success"}

FIX:added some codes

PHP:

```
$response_array = array('subject_code' => $subject_code,
                        'subject_name' => $subject_name,
                        'subject_course' => $subject_course,
                        'subject_day' => $subject_day,
                        'subject_time' => $subject_time,
                        'subject_year' => $subject_year,
                        'subject_section' => $subject_section,
                        'subject_room' => $subject_room);
```

change if/else statement to (PHP) :

```
if($stmt->affected_rows > 0){
    echo json_encode($response_array);
}
else{
    $response_array['status'] = 'error';
}
```

Comment: Go to the Network tab in developer tools, and look at the response to the AJAX call. Make sure there's nothing before or after the JSON.

Comment: You seem to be using `mysqli` to perform the query. Why are you using `mysql_real_escape_string`? First of all, you're mixing two different extensions, which isn't valid. Second, when you use prepared statements you should NOT escape the parameters.

Comment: `if($stmt)` won't tell you if the insert was successful. You need to use `if($stmt->affected_rows > 0)`.

Comment: sir @Barmar, sorry but I don't really know how to use the network tab, all i got here is (in order):
professor_home.php,
style.css,
jquery-1.11.1.min.js,
professor_home.js,
add_submit.php

about the mysql_real_escape_string, that was the code i used before, then research, i saw this prepared statements which could further enhance security, so i thought combining it would be good.

Comment: I guess it's time for you to learn how to debug Javascript using Developer Tools. There are some tutorials, google for them.

Comment: Look for `add_submit.php` and click on it. There will then be a tab labeled `Response`. Click on that to see the AJAX response.

Comment: ok, saw it .. brb, got an error with line 13-20 (undefined index) and a json_encode() error - undefined variable on add_submit.php. thank you for the reply sir.